# API call with Postman returns data but calling the same API with python does not return data

Tags: python, unirest

I am having trouble getting data back when programmatically calling an API. However, when I make the same call manually using Postman I get data back. Here is the code I used to make the call using python.

```
response = unirest.post(url='my api endpoint',
headers={"Accept": "application/json"}, params={"paramKey": [paramValue]})
print response.body
```

API call result: {"Success":true,"Message":null,"Data":[]}

Comment: What is the Status code? And error your getting?

Comment: I get status code: 200. Not getting any errors.

Comment: That's wrong how come u will get 200 for post request?

Comment: My understanding is that you get that code back if successful no matter what the http method call is.

Comment: Have a look at this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status when you send a data for server to post it should return 201 if the data is inserted And server accepts the data.

Comment: Check couple of things on Postman, like the return code you get there, and also if there's additional headers sent out. A full comparative example might help us help you (sent/received both in code and Postman)

Comment: Postman Header: Cache-Control →no-cache
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →449
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Tue, 29 Nov 2016 21:07:27 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET

Comment: Code Header: {u'Message': None, u'Data': [], u'Success': True}
200
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2016 21:05:18 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 41
Connection: Close

Comment: I notice a discrepancy in connection. In Postman, connection = keep-alive. In code header, connection = Close